# iPhone NFC and QR possibility

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nfc, qr-code

We are developing a game what is based on our engine. The concept of the engine is to read NFC and QR codes, launch our application, and send a request to our server, what is respond to the application. It's done on android.

We want to port this engine to iOs and Windows also. So our plan is to hire developers for this project. Before 4-5 month, we surprised, iPhone does not supports NFC, they will use iBeacon, but we was very happy, when we realized, iPhone 6 will have NFC reader. And then, after I made some research on the net, I was so sad, because I read everywhere, apples NFC is restricted the NFC to Apple Pay.

Because i really do not know apple devices, i have some questions.

Is it possible to do this with iOs? If NFC is not an option, can we do this with QR reader? If no, of course we won't hiring developers for iOs.

And i know, this is a stupid question, but maybe: does anybody know, what is apples plan in the future with NFC?

Comment: Both the iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+ have NFC. It is mentioned in the main iPhone 6 page http://www.apple.com/iphone-6/ as well as in the iPhone comparison. I think it is only for ApplePay at the moment but will prob be opened up at some point.

Comment: At this point in time (late 2014), I'd give up on NFC on iOS and rely on reading QR codes; primarily because there's no SDK at the moment and it's limited to only the newest devices. You should be either able to launch the application directly from the URL provided in the QR code, or send to your website which redirects back to the app based on platform sniffing - I'm not 100% au fait with the android URI registration which permits the first option.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, this was what i need. If you create an answer from it, i will accept that.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `QR` reader function in iOS app using C++ libraries: `ZXing` and `ZBar`. Personally I recomment you to use [`ZBar`](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/), it is better for `QR` codes but cannot read bar codes.

You can use [`iBeacons`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBeacon) with iOS.

Apple's `Passbook` application works through optical scanning of `QR` codes.

Comment: The next generation?! The iPhone 6 and 6+ have NFC. It's right there in the specs. The link you have posted is for the iPhone 5S release over a year ago.